# Android CardView corner radius not applying in Kitkat

Tags: android, material-design, android-cardview

I am working with `CardView` in android. I am trying to give corner radius to the `CardView`. I am able to do so from the XML. The code is working in expected way in Lollipop and above, but on android 4.4 devices, I am not seeing the corner radius being applied.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="20dp"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
    card_view:cardElevation="0dp">
```

Comment: remove `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"`
   `app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"`

Comment: @imi Refer this answer it will working perfect. I will tested it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50265768/6096821

Answer (score 1):

Put this code this will also works in 4.2.2 so obviously it will work for the Kitkat 4.4 version. I have already tested it right now.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:elevation="5dp">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Demo"/>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and Please don't forget to put the dependency :-

```
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it is really works for you.

Answer (score 0):

hope below code will help you

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/cvAddRes"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvHeading"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="3dp">
     </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try this in cardview write this two line.

```
card_view:cardCornerRadius="16sdp"
card_view:cardElevation="5sdp"
```